# PHPStorm 7.3.1 JSON formatter tool

Tags: json, plugins, ide, format, phpstorm

I use PHPstorm IDE and would like to find a plugin to format JSON so that it is easier for me to read.

Currently I have this in a file displayed in the IDE:

```
{"property":"value1","property2":"value2","array1":[{"attr1":"value1"},{"attr2":"value2"}]}
```

I would like a plugin I can run so that I can look at this instead:

```
{
   "property": "value1",
   "property2": "value2",
   "array1": [
      {
         "attr1": "value1"
      },{
         "attr2": "value2"
      }
   ]
}
```

I found the following plugin, but it does not seem to work with PHPStorm : http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3964?pr=

Comment: **Code | Reformat Code...** ? Although I do not think that IDE has enough Code Style rules to format it nicely (as it uses the same rules as for JavaScript) -- see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9379 and related tickets for that.

Comment: Reformatting the existing code might be problematic for further processing. There is no need to introduce linebreaks just for reading a json file decreasing any further programmatic reading speed. Usually users would want to 'see' the file beautified/formatted but do not need the file itself to be reformatted.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It is possibly because I'm new to PHPStorm, but the option in the menu **Code** -> **Reformat Code** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) does the job fine in a `.json file`, and goes an ok job in a `.js file`.

Press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> on MacOs.

Comment: It also works fine reformatting HTTP request's body parameters when they are given as JSON - you just need to select the JSON string and press `Ctrl+Shift+L`. Very handy.
(More on sending HTTP requests via PhpStorm can be found here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
to format files "json, html, php, ...." it's:
for window CTRL + ALT + L)
for mac: (Cmmand + Option + L).
```

Answer (score 1):

In phpStorm 2017

File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > JSON

Then set tab size, indent, and continuation indent.

Or "Set from..." if you have defined indentation for other code style and want to copy it.